# Text Positioning below titlebar

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to display some text just below title bar has shown below ,few text on left side and few on right side,how to align accordingly.

[image: display text]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ShowRoom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have to us this textview for the entire layout but need to postion one below the other in left left and right side has in image

Comment: You need to use custom action bar with textviews

Comment: Please expand your answer with what you already have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

titlebar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/titlebar" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Showroom" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="12345617890" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Ramakrisha Trippp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9876543210" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="13/1/2015" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Rohit Sharma" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Add this in your layout before setcontentView to hide your default action bar

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Thanks this worksfor me,i have the same code for titlebar but when i try add background image using andriod:src,it fails to set background imageview

Comment: try android:background

Comment: Do yu have any idea on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858216/list-of-item-display-with-scroll

Comment: hmmm:( can you post  here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939576/scrollable-list-of-items-in-a-table-format pls reply here